How to implement the TextChanged the CommunityToolkit MVVM way
I am using the .Net Maui's community toolkit and have some mvvm binding going on in a project.
I have a collectionview and a Searchbar connected to a ViewModel. I wish to implement the Searchbar's is TextChanged, but with no luck.
it is saying,

Event "Textchanged" can only be bound to properties of delegate type 'EventHandler'1'

I saw this Solution here on stack overflow, I however am using the COmmunityToolkit.
Xaml Code
public partial class CommunityPostsPagesViewModel : 
ObservableObject
{


private readonly ISecureStorageService _secureStorage;
private readonly IAppSettingGeneratorService _appsettingGenerator;
private readonly ICommunityPostCoreApiService 
 _communitypostService;
private readonly IClientCryptoGraphy _cryptoGraphy;
public CommunityPostsPagesViewModel(ISecureStorageService storage, 
ICommunityPostCoreApiService communitypostService
    , IAppSettingGeneratorService appsettingGenerator, 
IClientCryptoGraphy cryptoGraphy)
{
    _secureStorage = storage;
    _communitypostService = communitypostService;
    _appsettingGenerator = appsettingGenerator;
    _cryptoGraphy = cryptoGraphy;
    GetLastestComunityPost();
}


[ObservableProperty] 
string serchText;

[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<ComunityPostsModel> comunityPosts;

[RelayCommand]
async void SearchTextChanged()
{
    ComunityPosts.Clear();
    var output = new ObservableCollection<ComunityPostsModel>();
    try
    {
        var apiResponse = await _communitypostService.GetAll();
        var searchResponse = apiResponse.Response.Where(m => 
               m.Title.ToLower().Contains(SerchText.ToLower()));
        if (!searchResponse.Any())
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Oops!", $"There are 
                    currently no available community post with 
                     name: {SerchText}", "Ok");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var response in searchResponse)
            {
                output.Add(new ComunityPostsModel()
                {
                    DatePosted = response.DatePosted,
                    Body = response.Body,
                    Id = response.Id,
                    Title = response.Title

                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Oops!", "Could not get 
   any comunity Post", "Ok");
    }
    ComunityPosts = output;
}

[RelayCommand]
async void ComunityPostSelected(ComunityPostsModel input)
{


    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(CommunityPostPage), true, 
           new Dictionary<string, object>{
        {nameof(ComunityPostsModel),input}

    });

}

private async Task GetLastestComunityPost()
{
    var output = new ObservableCollection<ComunityPostsModel>();
    try
    {
        var apiResponse = await _communitypostService.GetAll();
        foreach (var response in apiResponse.Response)
        {
            output.Add(new ComunityPostsModel()
            {
                DatePosted = response.DatePosted,
                Body = response.Body,
                Id = response.Id,
                Title = response.Title
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }

    ComunityPosts = output;
}

}
For the Xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <ContentPage 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AE.Pages.CommunityPostsPage"
         Title="Community Beta"
          xmlns:viewmodel ="clr-namespace:AE.ViewModels"
        x:DataType="viewmodel:CommunityPostsPagesViewModel"
          xmlns:itemViewModel ="clr-namespace:AE.Models"
       xmlns:ur="http://schemas.enisn- 
       projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
         >

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
           Margin="25" Padding="25"
           >


<StackLayout>

  <SearchBar SearchCommand="{Binding SearchTextChangedCommand}" 
             Placeholder="Search Comunity Posts by Title" Text=" 
 {Binding SerchText}" 
             IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" TextChanged="{Binding 
  SearchTextChangedCommand}" Margin="00,00,00,25"/>
  <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ComunityPosts}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type 
   itemViewModel:ComunityPostsModel}" >
        <SwipeView  >
          <Frame>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source= 
  {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    viewmodel:CommunityPostsPagesViewModel}}, 
  Path=ComunityPostSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
    />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <StackLayout>
              <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="Bold"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding DatePosted}" 
  FontSize="Caption"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </Frame>
        </SwipeView>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  </CollectionView>


</StackLayout>


Textchanged can not bind Command, it is Event. You can use EventToCommandBehavior.

Please don't post code as images, always use text.

Alright, changed it from image to text @Julian, thanks

Have a look at this example which not only shows how to bind, search and present, but also how to throttle the query while user is typing

This seems to be good for WPF. I built a sample and tested it. It works.

You can use EventToCommandBehavior of CommunityToolkit to bind Command:
<SearchBar ....>
   <SearchBar.Behaviors>
       <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="TextChanged"
                Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}" />
   </SearchBar.Behaviors>
</SearchBar>


It works, thank you
